# Ajax Loading (pagination) posts disorders ajax post like

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm creating a blog and i want to load my posts via ajax , not pagination and i did.

**but the problem :**
I have ajax like system for each post but it only works for posts which are not loaded with ajax.

-- The PHP method to handle request:

```
public function load_more(){

        $offset = $this->input->post('loaded_count' , true) ? : 0 ;
        // for those who don't know codeigniter the line above is equal to $_POST['loaded_count']

        $posts = $this->mod->get_posts($offset);
        // gets posts array from database

        include_once "./application/views/inc/show-posts.php";
    }
```

in *show-posts.php* file i have my post template that does a foreach loop on *$posts* variable.

-- Ajax for loading posts:

```
$(".load-more-btn").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $posts_cont = $(".posts-container");
        var $loadedPostsCount = $this.attr('data-ppp');
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost/bona/ajax/load_more" ,
            type : 'post' ,
            data : {loaded_count : $loadedPostsCount} ,
            success : function(resp){
                $posts_cont.append(resp);
            },
            error : function(xhr){
                alert("error");
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });

    });
```

-- Ajax for liking post

```
$(".like-post").click(function(){
        var $postID = $(this).attr("data-class");
        var $this = $(this).find(".like-holder");
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost/bona/ajax/add_like') ?>",
            type : "post" ,
            data : { like_id : $postID } ,
            success : function (resp,s,x){
                $this.text(resp);
            } ,
            error : function(xhr){
                alert("error");
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
    });
```

1 : I put these two in ***$(document).ready()*** event.

2 : I get no errors on click and it looks like click event (to like) does not triggers for posts loaded by ajax.

3 : I am using Codeigniter

I think $(document).ready is causing this problem.

**How do you think?**

Comment: I would recommend using `id` instead of `class` for doing things like a click event so `<button id="like_post">Like</button>` and then your js would look like `$("#like_post").click(function(){` you could also do on form submit as well `$("#form_id_is_in_here").submit(function(e){`

Comment: What does your show-posts.php look like?

Comment: It's just a loop through the $posts array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$().click` event. This command works with all the nodes that are in your document at the time of execution, but does not work with elements loaded further.

You need to change `$().click with $().on("click", "", function())`.
[Here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is manual.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry. Can you tell us what changes did you make to use $().on()?
I think that what you need is $(".posts-container").on("click", ".like-holder", function (evt) { /*your code here*/ })

Comment: I think the problem is made by other things .
$().on() should work